# What's the idea about discouraging users from marking their own answer as correct?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I notice that you now have to wait 2 days or so before you can mark your own answer as the correct answer.  Why?

Comment: Wow, I thought you could never select your own answer as the right one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you haven't already, look at the relevant [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/why-cant-i-accept-my-own-answer/) [posts](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/). I think the main point is that immediately accepting your own answer discourages others from answering the question. Even if you could immediately accept your own answer, it would be a good idea to wait a couple of days; maybe somebody else has an awesome answer you never would have thought of.

Answer (score 3):

I wish there was a way to design the system so you can't accept *any* answer for two days. I feel like accepting an answer has an equivalent effect of closing the question, at least in the sense that it seems to discourage other users from submitting more/better answers.

**But that has other problems.** I know it is hard enough to get people revisiting their older questions, so putting a two-day moratorium on accepting answers would probably be a worse cure than the problem.

Comment: That's a great idea! Is it really that hard to get people to revisit their old questions? You could always give them some kind of gentle reminder (e.g. if you upvote an answer to your question, it suggests that maybe you should accept it). You get two points for accepting an answer, so there is some incentive to revisit your old questions.

Answer (score 2):

To give other users a chance to answer it. Maybe they have a better solution than you do.